# starting multiple long running background processes in one Command Prompt window?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, cmd

All I want is to start a bunch of background processes from the shell. That's all.

Here's what I have in a batch file called start_servers:

```
@ECHO OFF
call setenv
START "" /B xampp\apache_start.bat
START "" /B xampp\mysql_start.bat
START "" /B php start_daemon.php
echo Server started
```

when I run this by double clicking the batch file, it all works fine. I get the output of all 3 processes in 1 window.
However, if I start the shell in the same directory, type in 'start_servers.bat' and hit enter, it runs apache_start and mysql_start just fine, but the php script 'start_daemon' seemingly doesnt run, but I get 'Server started' outputted.

The weirdest thing though is If I hit enter once more, then php start_daemon.php runs!
It's as if 'php start_daemon.php' is being typed on my keyboard, but it's invisible to me.
When I hit enter, it appears like so:

```
[cwd]> start_servers.bat
...

[cwd]>Websocket Server started
Listening on: 0.0.0.0:9000
Master socket: Resource id #7
```

Notice the part '[cwd]>Server started' like I entered it as a command.

I've spent a whole day trying to work this out, It's driving me crazy!!!!!

Please please please help.

EDIT:

I've just been trying some other things and I'm still getting the same damn result.
If I reduce the .bat down to 'START "" /B php start_daemon.php' or if I simply type it into the commandline, I get the same result. First return, nothing. Second return, it runs.

I've also tried the following:

```
START "" /B node test.js
```

result:

```
C:\Users\hedge\Projects\PHPStorm\gpstudios>this is a test
```

what I expect:

```
this is a test
C:\Users\hedge\Projects\PHPStorm\gpstudios>
```

Also:

```
START "" /B python2 test.py
```

result:

```
C:\Users\hedge\Projects\PHPStorm\gpstudios>this is a test
```

And finally:

```
START "" /B python3 test.py
```

result:

```
C:\Users\hedge\Projects\PHPStorm\gpstudios>   [nothing, I hit return]
C:\Users\hedge\Projects\PHPStorm\gpstudios>   [nothing again, I hit return]
C:\Users\hedge\Projects\PHPStorm\gpstudios>this is a test
```

What on earth is going on? They all output the result to the line where I type my commands, which i suppose makes sense as the terminal is not waiting for the START call to finish before handing control back to me, however, PHP scripts require I hit return once more, and a Python3 script requires 2 returns!
This is not at all intuitive. Again, I plead for help. This is killing me.

EDIT 2:

If I run 'START "" /B /WAIT php start_daemon.php' or 'php start_daemon.php' then obviously, the script runs immediately and as expected, but it then freezes the shell and requires I start a new one in order to input any further commands.
I plan on running more than one background processes via node or php, but as it is I can only run one in a single CMD terminal.

I'm just trying to rephrase the problem a little in hope of getting some replies, if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put a temporisation before starting the PHP script  ?

```
@ECHO OFF
call setenv
START "" /B xampp\apache_start.bat
START "" /B xampp\mysql_start.bat
timeout 5 >nul
START "" /B php start_daemon.php
echo Server started
```

Comment: I'm afraid it didn't help. Still tearing my hair out over this... If I run the script consisting of just 'START "" /B php start_daemon.php' it still doesn't run on the first return. I have to hit return a second time before it runs.

Answer (score 0):

try grouping them all.
In other words, like this:

```
(@ECHO OFF
call setenv
START "" /B xampp\apache_start.bat
START "" /B xampp\mysql_start.bat
START "" /B php start_daemon.php
echo Server started)
```

By the way, if you copy/paste this whole thing in command prompt, it will run the first lines, then you press enter, and it will run the last one. Best thing to do of course is use a batch file when you run this command :D

P.S.
Thanks, I needed to know how to run stuff in the background. xD

UPDATE:

add a simple /timeout after each one:

```
(@ECHO OFF
call setenv
START "" /B xampp\apache_start.bat
timeout 1 >NUL
START "" /B xampp\mysql_start.bat
timeout 1 >NUL
START "" /B php start_daemon.php
timeout 1 >NUL
echo Server started)
```

Comment: It's hardly probable, that a block will change antyhing in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but I will try to explain at least some of the behaviour.

Using

```
START "" /B node test.js
```

result:

```
C:\Users\hedge\Projects\PHPStorm\gpstudios>this is a test
```

Can be expected, as starting `node test.js` asynchron normally takes some time to start.
Therefore the cmd.exe has finished the `Start` command and printed the prompt before the `node test.js` is able to print the text.

To avoid this you need to add a delay after the `start`.
I would recommend a batch file for this test.

```
@echo off
START "" /B node test.js
timeout /t 1 > nul
```

The problems that more `ENTER` keys are required for php or python seems to be a local problem with your system.
As a simple test works on Windows7.

```
@echo off
start "" /b php -r "echo 1;"
start "" /b php -r "echo 2;"
start "" /b php -r "echo 3;"
timeout /t 1 > nul
```

Running this multiple times, I get different outputs

> 213
>   123
>   ...

This can be expected, as every php instance starts asynchronously.